# How to do something if a marker is touched for 3 seconds

Tags: android, timer, android-mapview

I have an application with google maps api v2 with some markers on it. For each marker if I click on it it apears a ballon with some details about it title etc.
With SystemClock it only waits for 3 seconds but it does the action.

I want to do something if a user is pressing of X seconds on that marker? I tried using a thread but I did't manage to do it.

```
if (onBalloonTap(currentFocusedIndex, currentFocusedItem)) {
            long thisTime = 0;
            thisTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            if (thisTime > 3000) {

                DirectionsTask getDirectionsTask = new DirectionsTask();
                getDirectionsTask.execute(getCurrentLocation(),
                        currentFocusedItem.getPoint());
            }
```

Comment: it is possible to add OnTouchListener in your view ? like: `

boolean isActivated = false;  
view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getEventTime()-event.getDownTime()>3000 && !isActivated) {
                Toast.makeText(AudioPlayerActivity.this, "3 sec", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                isActivated = true; //avoid displaying a lot of toast
            }
            return true;
        }
});`

Comment: I am trying to do this in the itemizedoverlay.

Answer (score 0):

something like that ?

```
    GeoPoint p = null, currentP = null;
    boolean isActivated = false;
    view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() { 
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                isActivated = false;
                currentP = p ;
            }
            if(currentP == p && event.getEventTime()-event.getDownTime()>3000 && !) { 
                Toast.makeText(AudioPlayerActivity.this, "3 sec", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                isActivated = true; //avoid displaying a lot of toast } return true; } });
            }
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                currentP = null; p = null;
            }
        }
    });

     //extends Overlay type, works if the method is called when "action down"
     public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView    mapView)  {
          this.p = p;
          return true;
     }
```